# How can reduce recursion within this function

Tags: c++, recursion

can't figure out how to prevent recursion within this function, any suggestions or
recommendations? I've tried a couple of my own solutions but ran into the error of having
the program crash if wrong inputs and repeatedly entered.
Thanks in advance, DK.

```
static void CheckPlayerInput()
{
    // gets the character entered (as a char)
    cin >> input;

    //check is actually a char
    if (cin.fail())
    {
        //more recursion, could cause issues, could you find another way?
        cout << "Invalid character, try again!" << endl;
        CheckPlayerInput();
    }

    //converts char to upper case
    input = toupper(input);

    //check the input character
    // maps the input keys to the grid reference
    //calling the FillSquare method
    switch (input)
    {
    case '1': FillSquare(0, 0); break; //top-left
    case '2': FillSquare(0, 1); break; //top-centre
    case '3': FillSquare(0, 2); break; //top-right
    case '4': FillSquare(1, 0); break; //middle-left
    case '5': FillSquare(1, 1); break; //middle-centre
    case '6': FillSquare(1, 2); break; //middle-right
    case '7': FillSquare(2, 0); break; //bottom-left
    case '8': FillSquare(2, 1); break; //bottom-centre
    case '9': FillSquare(2, 2); break; //bottom-right
        //IF NOT ANY OF THE ABOVE
    default:
    {
        //more recursion, could cause issues
        //
        cout << "Invalid character, try again!" << endl;
        CheckPlayerInput();
    }
    break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Because you cannot control the user, you cannot control the recursion. Use iteration instead.

Comment: This type of interaction (repeating something until certain conditions are met) is usually handled with a **loop**.  You could put that whole function in a loop and just replace `break` with `return`.

Comment: You would want to either ensure that the compiler is using Tail Call Optimization (TCO) or unwind the recursion into a loop. (Accumulate the value and loop while it doesn't pass validation)

Comment: At the very least you could put a `return;` at the end of the `if (cin.fail())` block so that after the recursive call to `CheckPlayerInput()` returns, you won't run the rest of the method.

Comment: The best way to reduce the recursion in this function is to remove it completely. `do { promot_for_input(); validate_input(); } while (input_is_invalid());`. Recursion is not appropriate here.

Comment: Always try to avoid recursion. It's more difficult to understand for other programmers and it's much, much slower if not optimized by the compiler

Comment: Disagree with above comment. There are many situations where the recursive approach is easier to understand than the iterative approach and easier to optimize. It's the sort of thing you need to chose on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `do` `while` loop instead

```
static void CheckPlayerInput()
{
    bool invalid = false;
    do
    {
        invalid = false;
        // gets the character entered (as a char)
        cin >> input;
...
        default:
        {
            //more recursion, could cause issues
            //
            cout << "Invalid character, try again!" << endl;
            invalid = true;
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    while(invalid);
}
```

The while loop will repeat as long as the input is invalid

Comment: this would flow a lot better with a `while (!valid) {` i feel.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are many different ways to implement it.
The below might be my approach.

Note:

- Filling the square feels like a dedicated task and should therefore be inside it's own function.
- Maybe you should use non-static / non-global methods and instead use objects.
- Your method `CheckPlayerInput` is not *checking* the input. Instead, it's *processing* it.

```
static bool 
_fillSquare(char type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
    case '1': FillSquare(0, 0); break; //top-left
    case '2': FillSquare(0, 1); break; //top-centre
    case '3': FillSquare(0, 2); break; //top-right
    case '4': FillSquare(1, 0); break; //middle-left
    case '5': FillSquare(1, 1); break; //middle-centre
    case '6': FillSquare(1, 2); break; //middle-right
    case '7': FillSquare(2, 0); break; //bottom-left
    case '8': FillSquare(2, 1); break; //bottom-centre
    case '9': FillSquare(2, 2); break; //bottom-right

    default : return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}


// this method does not `check` the player input, but it
// `processes` it. The name should reflect that.
static void 
processPlayerInput()
{
   // try to retrieve and process input until 
   //  a valid input was given

   while (true)
   {
      cin >> input;                
      
      if (!cin.fail ())
         continue;
      
      input = toupper(input);
      bool success = _fillSquare(input);
      if (!success)
      {
         cout << "Invalid character, try again!" << endl;
         continue;
      }
      
      return;           
   }
}
```